# PHP explode function print ArrayArrayArray

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am having a problem trying to explode an array, connection to database works and tested, the commented print line works, but the explode doesn't, every time i explode the item it
prints ArrayArrayAray. I have been stuck on this for so long, looked everywhere, followed examples but to no avail. If anyone could help it will be much appreciated.

```
          $result_ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " .PRODUCT_INSTRUCTIONS. " order by group_code") or  
                        die($errorhandler->add("ERROR", __FILE__ . "=>" . __CLASS__ . "=>" . __FUNCTION__ . "=>" . __LINE__, "Failed getting items." . mysql_error()));

                         while($rows_=  mysql_fetch_array($result_)){
                                  $instruction = $rows_['instructions'];
                                 // print "<tr><td>".$rows_['group_code']."</td></tr>"." <tr><th>".$instruction."</th></tr>";
                                  $inst = explode("|", $instruction);

                                  for($i = 0; $i < count($inst); $i++){
                                      echo $inst;
                                  }

                              }

                        ?>
```

Comment: You are `echo $inst;`ing each time. In other words, you are outputting *the array* each time, *not* the array's contents.

Comment: `echo $inst[$i]`...!?

Comment: Explode returns an array of strings, I think you should echo $inst[$i];

Comment: Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the index to the `echo` command.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($inst); $i++){
    echo $inst[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($inst); $i++)
{
    //If $inst is an array it will print the array else it print as string
    if(is_array($inst))
        print_r($inst);
    else
        echo $inst;
}
```

Comment: When entering code in an answer, it's best to explain what it does.

Answer (score 0):

To print off arrays, use `var_dump()` instead.

```
$instruction = $rows('instructions');
                             // print "<tr><td>".$rows_['group_code']."</td></tr>"." <tr><th>".$instruction."</th></tr>";
                              $inst = explode("|", $instruction);

                              for($i = 0; $i < count($inst); $i++){
                                  echo $inst[$i];
                              }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
echo $inst;
```

with

```
print_r($inst);
```

Comment: This isn't what he asked in the code, he wants the loop to echo each element, not dump the array 3 times.

Comment: Yes you right, your answer is correct, need to write echo $inst[$i].